# Laravel Eloquent. I try to intersect two intermediate table. Is there any query more efficient than this?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel Eloquent. I try to intersect two intermediate table. Is there any query more efficient than this ?

Unit Model :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Product Model :

```
public function units()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Unit');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

User Model :

```
public function units()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Unit');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Query Eloquent :

```
Product::get()

->filter(function ($product) {
    return $product->units
                    ->pluck('id')
                    ->intersect(auth()->user()->units->pluck('id'))
                    ->isNotEmpty();
})
```

I try to retrieve all product where product unit is equal user login unit

---

### **UPDATE**

I think code below is more clean

```
Product::whereHas('units', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where([
        'units.id' => auth()->user()->units->pluck('id'),
    ]);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solutions looks optimal! It looks like a way to compare attributes from two pivot tables in the way

```
Product::with('users')
        ->with('units')
        ->compareAttributesFromPivotTables('attribute_a','attribute_b')
        ->get();
```

isn't yet implemented.