# How to access data from multiple many to many relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a database with the following tables:

**products**

- id
- name

**materials**

- id
- name

**units**

- id
- name

products and materials table has many to many relationships, also materials and units table have many to many relationships as well so these are 2 pivot tables

**material_product**

- material_id
- product_id

**material_unit**

- material_id
- unit_id

Now from these relations, I know about the material that is used in the product but how will I find out the associated unit of each material as there are many to many relations between materials and units table.

For example, if there is a `Product-A` which has `Aluminum` as one of the material and `Aluminum` is linked to both `Kg` and `Ton` on units table. Now how will I get the correct unit of `Aluminum` when I access the `Product-A`.

Can I do this in Laravel, instead of making materials and products relation I relate products table to material_unit pivot table as such

**material_unit_product**

- product_id
- material_unit_id

and yes then there will be an increment field in material_unit table as well which will act as **id** so material_unit table will be

**material_unit**

- id
- material_id
- unit_id
- *unique([material_id, unit_id)]*

Or can I use the **id** from the material_unit pivot table in the material_product pivot table as an extra field?

Or is this a better way to do this type of relationship in Laravel? I don't know how to do this properly, any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the use-case I would think that it is indeed an option to use the `material_unit_id` and `product_id` in `material_product`. Depending on what you are storing that is. I would consider the `material_unit` a list of possible units to use for this material, and `material_unit_product` a list of concrete material units that belong to a product. You might even consider a table with all 3 id's in them: `material_id`, `unit_id`, `product_id`. This way you simply say: This product has this material in this unit.

Comment: @RobBiermann thanks for the comment, Does Laravel model support connecting 3 tables in one pivot table, is there any way we can use it in eloquent relation? I am also thinking of adding `material_unit_id` in `material_product` pivot table? But I don't think it is the best approach.

Comment: why don't material and unit used one to one relationship ? is `Aluminum `  sometimes contain `liter` unit ? non sense right ?

Comment: @ElboS.P. Yes, that is kinda nonsense but Alumiumn is sometimes measured in m^3 when we want to represent volume while sometimes it is represented in terms of weight (Kg or Ton, etc)

Comment: Is aluminum has more than one unit at the same time ? If no, you can attach unit_id at your product column, one to one relationship. If yes, you can use this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61660436/laravel-eloquent-my-pivot-table-has-relation) solution. I have same problem too. Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Or you could use this approach (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625336/laravel-eloquent-i-try-to-intersect-two-intermediate-table-is-there-any-query)

Comment: @ElboS.P. Yes, Aluminum has more than one unit at the same time. Thanks for pointing me to those links. Instead of adding `id` to **material_unit** pivot table we can use `id` of **units** table and link it to **material_product** pivot table, in that way we can avoid the creation of **material_unit** pivot table.

Comment: Is it help ? Hope you saves much time ^_^

Comment: Yeah, it did help. Thanks @ElboS.P.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searches and posting the same question on another forum, I came to know that there is no such Laravel way to handle this problem. 
What helped me is I used the `id` of pivot table **material_unit** as a foreign key in the **material_product** pivot table and it worked fine. I just had to specify it in the model while defining a relationship using `withPivot`. After that, I can easily get the `id` of the material_unit pivot table and using that `id` I was able to find the related unit of the material for that specific product.

Comment of *RobBiermann* on this question and comment of [*bugsyha*](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-access-data-from-multiple-many-to-many-relationships?page=1#reply=608748) from Laracast forum also helped me use this approach.